# How to reinitialize a Spring Bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, initialization, spring-bean

Is it possible to reinitialize a Spring Bean on runtime?

My Bean uses static settings which in some cases change and then I have to reinitialize the Bean.

Comment: You can access the bean from context right, and then just create a method `update` inside the bean class, which you can call based on your trigger to update the bean.

Comment: My bean is a function inside a configuration class. Does a update function works for this constilation?

Comment: Yes even if you create bean from a method, it is still an object inside spring context and can be accessed like any other bean.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have three options to update singleton bean in spring context, you can chose one suitable for your use case:

**Reload method In the Bean**

Create a method in your bean which will update/reload its properties. Based on your trigger, access the bean from spring context, and then call the reload method to update bean properties (since singleton) it will also be updated in spring context & everywhere it is autowired/injected.

**Delete & Register Bean in Registry**

 You can use `DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry` to remove & re-register your bean. The only drawback to this, it will not refresh/reload old instance of already autowired/injected bean in consumer classes.

```
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) context.getBeanFactory();
registry.destroySingleton({yourbean}) //destroys the bean object
registry.registerSingleton({yourbeanname}, {newbeanobject}) //add to singleton beans cache
```

**@RefreshScope**

Useful for refreshing bean value properties from config changes. But it has very limited & specific purpose. [Resource](https://github.com/jeroenbellen/blog-manage-and-reload-spring-properties) to read more about it.

Comment: It's so hard to reload properties.

Comment: Why not just `bean = applicationContext.getBean(Bean.class)`?

Comment: Because it will just get you the already loaded bean from the context, and not refresh/reload it. I don't understand when you say, it's so hard ?

Comment: Create a public init method to reload all properties, use the same in constructor & reload call.

Comment: In my case new bean is returned on `applicationContext.getBean(Bean.class)`. It's because of 
`@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)`.

Comment: Yeah this question doesn't apply for non-singleton beans. Prototype scope is per use, so your bean is created new for every demand, so no question of reloading applies.

Comment: I have tried to fetch the DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry from the ApplicationContext
`DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) context.getBeanFactory();`
the `context` object is of type `ApplicationContext`
but I got the following error `The method getBeanFactory() is undefined for the type ApplicationContext`
And also suggests `change to getParentBeanFactory(..)`
Help is much appreciated

Comment: I've found a wrong information in a tutorial "The registerSingleton() method not only creates the bean in the context but also autowires it to the dependent objects." [baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-reinitialize-singleton-bean). I've tested, and this reloading into dependent beans  doesn't exist, therefore this response it is still the best.

Comment: @Abhilash - Your question skipped my attention. And its very late to serve you any good but just putting my comments here so others can benefit in future.
>> context is type `ConfigurableApplicationContext`.