# Can we toggle swagger on/off without restarting the application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-2.0

I've seen different approaches on how to either disable or enable swagger(eg: @Profile etc) but none are useful when you want to use swagger, you can just enable and disable it when done on a running application without restart.

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to do it or workarounds, but no direct spring swagger configuration which you can use. I am gonna jot dot some options/steps I can think for you, which you can try.

## Option 1

1. Create a `filterchain` for swagger URI, which will check, say a property name `swagger.enable` `true/false`, accordingly forward or reject the request.
2. Either expose a post endpoint to update this property using `env.setProperty` or keep this property in `application.properties` & create reload feature. Some [reference](https://jeroenbellen.com/manage-and-reload-spring-application-properties-on-the-fly/) here for reload.

## Option 2

1. Create your docket bean from property like below:

   @Bean
   public Docket api() {
       return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
              .... .build().enable(env.getProperty("swagger.enable"));
   }
2. Ref `Option 1 : Step#2`
3. Add logic to [reinitialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean/51218781?noredirect=1#comment97190475_51218781) the `Docket` bean based on trigger, may be as followup action of step#2 endpoint.

So your swagger URI will work based on current state of this property, which you are controlling, thus will not require restart.