# Re-inject CDI bean if some injected property changed

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, cdi, weld

I have a bean BeanA with injected property `private int url`:

```
class BeanA { @Value(${"db.url"}) private String url; private DbConnection connection; }
```

Let us say this `Value` annotation is similar to Spring `Value`. During initialization, connection will be initialized by using injected property into url field. And also there is some `PostConstruct and PreDestroy` methods in `BeanA`. 
My question is: is it possible to dynamically reinstantiate `BeanA` when `url`   property changed. I have mechanism of detecting property change. For now, I just re-inject this url only, but I want to recreate this bean, initialize new connection and re-inject this bean in all dependetn beans. I dont use Spring Cloud Config.

Comment: The @RefreshScope looks helpful in this answer: (But it's depending on Spring Cloud) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean

Comment: Yes, but it is from Spring. I dont use Spring. The only way i see now is implementing my own RefreshScope with Context.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use spring at all, I suggest:

1. Leave the "bean" as is. (So it will serve as Singleton).
2. add a method in the bean: getConnection()
3. When the property changes, recreate a new connection inside that bean.
4. Any component that needs the connection will always call the bean's getConnection() and it will always get the most updated connection instance.

**OR**

You might want to use a Proxy design pattern where your bean is used by the client but internally refers to another connection bean (the "target" bean) and the target may be replaced with a new instanse of a completely new bean. But always, the client/user holds the same reference to the proxy.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that I`m writing a lib. So if client will use it, I just want to re-load his bean once property of that bean will change and I think it should be possible to do in some generic way.

Comment: 1. So is this a pure Java class?  2. Is the bean part of the lib or is it a user class? I mean, it can still be a class where the user always have the same reference to it but the state of the class changes. (as described in the answer above). Otherwise, you might want to use a Proxy design pattern where your bean is used by the client but internally refers to another connection bean (the "target" bean) and the target may be replaced with a new instanse of a completely new bean.  But always, the client/user holds the same reference to the proxy.

Comment: Sorry, this is just an example. I meant that I want to somehow reload beans (re-instantiate and re-inject in all dependent beans) once their properties changed and I re-injected those properties, like I did with this url.

Comment: Ok, if I understood you correctly, I should wrap my instance in some proxy and inject this proxy to all dependent beans and once internal state of actual instance will change, I re-instantiate only target instance but all dependent beans will not change dependency on proxy. Smth like that?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'll also revise my answer to include this proxy option...

Comment: Ok, I`ll try this solution and will leave my comment after that. Thanks!