# Customise user login behaviour in OAuth based B2B multi tenant Spring Boot application using Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am working on a Spring Boot application, which has two tenants as of now: `tenant1` and `tenant2` (in the future, I will add more tenants). Each of the tenants has its own authentication providers.

In order to achieve the same, as of now, I have made the following changes in my application:

config changes are as follows:

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant1.client-id=abcd
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant1.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant1.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
myapp.oauth2.path=https://external.authorization.server/services/oauth2/
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant1.token-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant1.authorization-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant1.user-info-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant1.user-name-attribute=name
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant2.client-id=efgh
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant2.client-secret=secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant2.client-authentication-method=basic
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant2.authorization-grant-type=authorization_code
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant2.token-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant2.authorization-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant2.user-info-uri=${myapp.oauth2.path}userinfo
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.tenant2.user-name-attribute=name
```

As of now, I am fetching client secrets for both tenants from Vault, so I had to define the OAuth2 configuration as follows:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties(OAuth2ClientProperties.class)
@Conditional(ClientsConfiguredCondition.class)
@Configuration
public class OAuth2Configuration {

  static final String OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY = "oauth2_client_secret";
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(OAuth2Configuration.class);
  private static final String OAUTH2_REGISTRATION_MISSING =
      "oAuth2 registration properties are missing";
  private final ApplicationSecretProvider applicationSecretProvider;
  private final Map<String, ClientAuthenticationMethod> clientAuthenticationMethodMap =
      new HashMap<>();
  private final String authenticationMethod;

  public OAuth2Configuration(
      @Value("${spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.tenant1.client-authentication-method}")
      final String authenticationMethod,
      final ApplicationSecretProvider applicationSecretProvider) {
    this.authenticationMethod = authenticationMethod;
    this.applicationSecretProvider = applicationSecretProvider;
    this.clientAuthenticationMethodMap
        .put(ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST.getValue(), ClientAuthenticationMethod.POST);
    this.clientAuthenticationMethodMap
        .put(ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC.getValue(), ClientAuthenticationMethod.BASIC);
    this.clientAuthenticationMethodMap
        .put(ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE.getValue(), ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE);
  }

  @Bean
  public InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository getClientRegistrationRepository(
      OAuth2ClientProperties properties) {

    List<ClientRegistration> registrations = new ArrayList<>(
        OAuth2ClientPropertiesRegistrationAdapter.getClientRegistrations(properties).values());
    //We will have only one client registered for oAuth
    if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(registrations)) {
      log.error(OAUTH2_REGISTRATION_MISSING);
      throw new IllegalStateException(OAUTH2_REGISTRATION_MISSING);
    }
    ClientRegistration registration = registrations.get(0);
    ClientRegistration.Builder builder = ClientRegistration.withClientRegistration(registration);

    ClientAuthenticationMethod clientAuthenticationMethod =
        getClientAuthenticationMethod(authenticationMethod);
    
    ClientRegistration completeRegistration = builder
        .clientSecret(applicationSecretProvider.getSecretForKey(OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET_KEY))
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(clientAuthenticationMethod)
        .build();

    ClientRegistration testRegistration = registrations.get(1);
    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(List.of(completeRegistration, testRegistration));
  }

  protected ClientAuthenticationMethod getClientAuthenticationMethod(String grantType) {
    ClientAuthenticationMethod retValue = clientAuthenticationMethodMap.get(grantType);
    if (retValue == null) {
      return ClientAuthenticationMethod.NONE;
    }
    return retValue;
  }
}
```

Then I extended DefaultOAuth2UserService in order to save user details in my application as follows:

```
@Component
public class CustomOAuth2UserService extends DefaultOAuth2UserService {

  private UserRepository userRepository;
  private AuthorityRepository authRepository;    
  
  @Autowired
  public void setUserRepository(UserRepository userRepository) {
    this.userRepository = userRepository;
  }    
  
  @Autowired
  public void setAuthorityRepository(AuthorityRepository
                                                  authorityRepository) {
    this.authorityRepository = authorityRepository;
  }

  @Override
  public OAuth2User loadUser(OAuth2UserRequest userRequest)  {
    DefaultOAuth2User oAuth2User = (DefaultOAuth2User) super.loadUser(userRequest);
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<>(oAuth2User.getAuthorities());
    Map<String, Object> attributes = oAuth2User.getAttributes();
    ...
    return new DefaultOAuth2User(authorities, oAuth2User.getAttributes(), userNameAttributeName);
  }
}
```

Security configuration is as follows:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Import(SecurityProblemSupport.class)
@ConditionalOnProperty(
        value = "myapp.authentication.type",
        havingValue = "oauth",
        matchIfMissing = true
)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  private final CustomOAuth2UserService customoAuth2UserService;
 
  public SecurityConfiguration(CustomOAuth2UserService customoAuth2UserService) {
    this.customoAuth2UserService = customoAuth2UserService;
  }

  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
        .csrf()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/manage/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/auth-info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/management/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/info").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/prometheus").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/management/**").hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            //.and().oauth2ResourceServer().jwt()
            .and()
            //.and()
        .oauth2Login()
            .redirectionEndpoint()
                .baseUri("/oauth2**")
                .and()
            .failureUrl("/api/redirectToHome")
            .userInfoEndpoint().userService(customoAuth2UserService);
    http.cors().disable();
  }
}
```

With this on `/login` page, users from both the tenants are able to see both the login links.

I have following question in this regard:

(1) Instead of showing multiple links on the login page, would like to have a common entry page for all users, where users can enter the email and based on tenant id (derived from email), user can be redirected to the appropriate authentication provider and post successful authentication, authenticated user details can be saved in application database as done in `CustomOAuth2UserService`. How would I achieve this?

In this regard, I have gone through several articles/posts but did not get any concrete idea regarding what changes should I do in the existing code base to achieve this.

Comment: The login page is part of the OAuth2 authorization server. If you use more than one authorization server, you can't have only one login page. However, you could use a custom page with only one input field for email and redirect the user to the login page of the authorization server. But the offtrade is, that your user has to enter his/her email twice.

Comment: Your second question is - at least for me - unclear. Look at other applications, there are always a login page with links to the authorization servers like Google and Facebook. That's the way it works. Why is that not enough?

Comment: @dur Actually regarding the first question, I want the behavior as you mentioned in the first comment, i.e. based on the email id entered, the user, will be redirected to the corresponding auth server. But I did not find any idea regarding how to do this. 

Let me try to clarify the second question,  my application is meant for B2B. Say, tenant A would like to use my application, they can add my app to its portfolio, which can contain other apps as well. Now whenever an already logged-in user of A clicks on the icon my app, he/she logs in without entering an email id like above.

Comment: For the first question: write your own custom login page with Thymeleaf and a Spring MVC controller. Only add one inpute field, submit it to your controller. The controller redirects the user to the right autorization service. That's just a simple page as any other page in your application.

Comment: For your second question, the tenant has to link your app with the right URL. That one for the tenant. This  link would redirect to the autorization server, which doesn't show the login page, because the user is already logged in and it would redirect to your application. This works as long as the authorization server doesn't show login page for logged in users. With some providers (for example Google) you could configure it. So the only thing you have to do is, to give the right URL to your tenant.

Comment: @dur Okay. Regarding your suggestion for first question, I have two doubts:

1. Should I remove oauth2login() from the config() function in Security Configuration ?
2. In my application, I save authenticated user details in the database as mentioned in the OP. In the approach that you suggested, how would I do this ?

Comment: 1. I think, you need it for the redirection links, but you have to try it. 2. I see no problem, why should that be a problem? You have nothing to change.

Comment: @Joy were you able to achieve this requirement having one login and redirecting to login based on tenant ? I have a similar requirement where we want to use the subdomain for each tenant and based on the tenant that we identify, we want to redirect the user to their auth provider. Your insights would help.