# Reflect env variable reload to java bean

Tags: java, json, spring, refresh, spring-bean

```
public static final String STUDENTS = "studentsInfo";
     @Bean(name = "students")
      public List<Student> getStudents() {
        String configuredStudents = env.getProperty("studentsInfo"); //JSON having list of students info
        List<Student> students;
        if (configuredStudents != null) {
          try {
            students =
                Arrays.asList(
                    JsonUtilFactory.getInstance(JsonUtilFactory.JsonUtilType.LOCAL)
                        .toObject(configuredStudents, Student[].class));
          } catch (Exception e) {
           
          }
        }
        return students;
      }
```

1. I'm able to refresh env variable [i.e without system restart `@RefreshScope` and `spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config`]. How to make those changes to bean students ?
2. Also if I have to partially update JSON [say add a new student], what would be the right approach?

Answer (score 1):

While I am not sure why you want to create bean of all students, below are my suggestions.

```
DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) context.getBeanFactory();
registry.destroySingleton({yourbean}) //destroys the bean object
registry.registerSingleton({yourbeanname}, {newbeanobject}) //add to singleton beans cache
```

[How to reinitialize a Spring Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean)

A better approach will be to store them in a noSql database and return the list or if you want to read from file override DataSource to read from file.