# Reconfigure Spring Integration beans at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I have this configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class SftpConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private InterfaceRepository interfaceRepo;

    public record SessionFactoryKey(String host, int port, String user) {
    }

    @Bean
    SessionFactoryLocator<LsEntry> sessionFactoryLocator() {

        Map<Object, SessionFactory<LsEntry>> factories = interfaceRepo.findAll().stream()
                .map(x -> new SimpleEntry<>(new SessionFactoryKey(x.getHostname(), x.getPort(), x.getUsername()),
                        sessionFactory(x.getHostname(), x.getPort(), x.getUsername(), x.getPassword())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (a, b) -> a));

        return new DefaultSessionFactoryLocator<>(factories);
    }

    @Bean
    RemoteFileTemplate<LsEntry> fileTemplateResolver(DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory) {
        return new SftpRemoteFileTemplate(delegatingSessionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory(SessionFactoryLocator<LsEntry> sessionFactoryLocator) {
        return new DelegatingSessionFactory<>(sessionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Bean
    RotatingServerAdvice advice(DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory) {

        List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories = interfaceRepo.findAll().stream()
                .filter(Interface::isReceivingData)
                .map(x -> new RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory(
                        new SessionFactoryKey(x.getHostname(), x.getPort(), x.getUsername()),
                        x.getDirectory()))
                .toList();

        return keyDirectories.isEmpty() ? null : new RotatingServerAdvice(delegatingSessionFactory, keyDirectories);

    }

    @Bean
    PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store() {
        return new PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore();
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow(ObjectProvider<RotatingServerAdvice> adviceProvider,
            DelegatingSessionFactory<LsEntry> delegatingSessionFactory, PropertiesPersistingMetadataStore store) {
        
        RotatingServerAdvice advice = adviceProvider.getIfAvailable();

        return advice == null ? null
                : IntegrationFlows
                        .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(delegatingSessionFactory)
                                .filter(new SftpPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter(store, "rotate_"))
                                .localDirectory(new File("C:\\tmp\\sftp"))
                                .localFilenameExpression("#remoteDirectory + T(java.io.File).separator + #root")
                                .remoteDirectory("."), e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(1).advice(advice)))
                        .channel(MessageChannels.queue("files")).get();
    }

    private SessionFactory<LsEntry> sessionFactory(String host, int port, String user, String password) {
        DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory(true);
        factory.setHost(host);
        factory.setPort(port);
        factory.setUser(user);
        factory.setPassword(password);
        factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Basically it provides a `RemoteFileTemplate` that allows to upload files via SFTP, and an `IntegrationFlow` that polls a set of SFTP servers to retrieve files. The configuration is loaded via a database.

I want to reload the beans when the configuration has changed in the database but I can't figure out how.

I think the only chance I have to make it work is to use lazy proxies because the client code has already loaded bean instances which cannot be unloaded. That's why I tried `@RefreshScope` from spring cloud, but it didn't work because `IntegrationFlow` forbids other scopes than `singleton`.

Is there any solution other than closing the application context and run `SpringApplication.run` again?

Comment: here are some approaches how to reload beans in general, maybe this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51218086/how-to-reinitialize-a-spring-bean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your current configuration, only what you need to reload is a configuration for SFTP servers. So, you need to refresh only `sessionFactoryLocator` and `RotatingServerAdvice` beans.

According to the `org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.refresh.RefreshScope`, we need to have standard lifecycle callback on a bean for a proper refreshment. The `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator` doesn't have one to clean up its internal `Map`, so we probably need to catch a `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent` and call `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator.removeSessionFactory()` for a clear state. However if you would just use simple keys for factory entries, then standard `@RefreshScope`  would be enough: the `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator` would be reinitialized and its internal map would be just overridden for the same key, but new values. Not sure why you decided to go some complex `SessionFactoryKey` abstraction based on a connection info.

The `RotatingServerAdvice` does not need any extra work: just `@RefreshScope` should be enough. That `RotatingServerAdvice(DelegatingSessionFactory<?> factory, List<RotationPolicy.KeyDirectory> keyDirectories)` constructor overrides all the instance internals.

Comment: Thanks for your complete and clear answer. There's just one thing I don't get: if I have multiple servers to poll, isn't the tuple "hostname", "port", and "user" a good key for the session factory? Are you saying that the only purpose of the locator is to have one session factory per thread? If so, how do I populate the keys before the threads exist?

Comment: Well, that is also OK, but technically we suggest to have just some logical key which could be accessed from the `RotatingServerAdvice`. But I see your point: you may not know how many servers you have in the config. So, yes, then your `SessionFactoryKey` is good. But you need to clean up your `SessionFactoryLocator` some way. Although since your `RotatingServerAdvice` will never use old keys, it might be OK to not worry about old entries...

Comment: Ok thanks. Last thing, you are saying that the `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator` can't clear its internal `Map` and that I have to call `DefaultSessionFactoryLocator.removeSessionFactory()` in a `RefreshScopeRefreshedEvent`  listener. According to me annotating `sessionFactoryLocator` with `@RefreshScope` will call the bean factory to create a fresh one which will be provided by the proxy whose reference is held by the `DelegatingSessionFactory`. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Yes, you are right: I misread that `RefreshScope` Javadoc. Cannot confirm though, since I don't have any code to play with.